# Dirichlet Self-Convolution Inversion

Tags: mobius-inversion, dirichlet-convolution

I am interested in finding out a method to invert Dirichlet selfconvolution.

In math expressions it means: **Find out $a$ once $b=a*a$ is known**

So a kind of squareroot of the Dirichlet product.

I also found that Mobius inversion formula clearly states an inversion for $b=a*1$:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula

but I found no similar result for selfconvolution.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a(1)\ne 0$.

By induction once you know $a(1)$ and $a(d)$ for $d| n, d<n$ and $\sum_{d| n} a(d)a(n/d)$ then you know $a(n)$. Thus the only indeterminate is $a(1)$ which is one of the two square roots of $b(1)$.

If $a(1)=0$ it works the same way except we are dealing with the generalized Dirichlet series $(\sum_{n\ge N} a(n)(n/N)^{-s})^2= \sum_{n\ge N^2} b(n)(n/N^2)^{-s}$

Comment: I expected this induction procedure could be understood as $a=b*f$ for a certain $f(n)$ arithmetic función.

Comment: Well, no ${}{}{}{}$